# What is "Irish Moss"?

Tags: food-identification

I'm trying to reproduce a recipe mentioned in a novel for a beverage, and it mentions that the main character threw in some "irish moss". I assume this isn't literally just moss from Ireland. What is this? Does it have another name I might be able to buy it under?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Irish Moss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chondrus_crispus), *Chondrus crispus*, is a species of seaweed, rich in [carrageenan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrageenan), an emulsifier and hydrocolloid.

Evidently, you can buy modern [extracts](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/irish-moss-1-oz.html) as well from brewing supply stores, for use as a kettle fining to help precipitate unwanted proteins.

Comment: Exactly this. Try your local homebrew supply store; it's most commonly used to keep the beverage clear.